# Show Templates in Custom Post Type Editor

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, templates

I know I can use templates for my custom post types like this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Template_Files

But I would like to have a dropdown menu to choose a template, like that when you create a new page.

How can i get that on the edit page of my custom post type?
I expected it to be here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#supports
But unfortunately it's not.

Comment: Based on https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L789, the templates drop down is only available for the 'page' post type

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can do that as a page in Wordpress, but I have another idea..

You can add a new taxonomy for your posttype template, like categories, then create a custom field for your posttype, (do the metabox) to show templates.